# Graphql sending site data for another project environment

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud

I have set up 2 projects on XM Cloud sandbox environment.

[image]

Generating GraphQL EdgeToken from PS (`.\New-EdgeToken.ps1 -EnvironmentId <environmentId>`) for Project's (`xmcloud-edge-integration`) environment(dev).

But always GraphQL API returns a response from another project's (`xmcloud-edge-2401`) environment(`xmcloud-edge-2401-devenv`).

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear, how you are doing the graphql query. Have you specified the Endpoint,
The possible endpoints based on the URL of the cm instance are:

https://xmcloud-edge-integration.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge

https://xmcloud-edge-2401.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge

And you need to use the correct API key.

Or if you want to use Experience Edge:

https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1

Please keep in mind, that the edge endpoint is the same for all customers/projects, the edge identifies the endpoint by the "sc_apikey" header which contains the Edge Token.

If you are using for example nextjs, you need to specify the correct endpoint and API key for these variables (docker):

```
JSS_EDITING_SECRET=
SITECORE_API_KEY=sitecore API key
SITECORE_API_HOST=https://xmcloud-edge-2401.sitecorecloud.io
GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT= https://xmcloud-edge-2401.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge
```

If this answer didn't help, please provide a bit more detail about the way your are running the query.
you can always test your query using a GUI:

```
https://[your instance].sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge/ide
```